# How can I put border styling with react-stripe-elements input component?

Tags: reactjs, stripe-payments

About this React component library.

- https://github.com/stripe/react-stripe-elements

How can I put border styling with input component?

```
<CardElement style={{
  base: {
    fontSize: '18px',
    border: '1px solid red' // it is not work.
  } 
}} />
```

but, seems they didn't provide custom style interface, though.

- https://stripe.com/docs/elements/reference#element-options\

Anyone know?

**Update:**

following are sample code that using `StripeElement` class to apply custom styling.

```
.StripeElement {
  border: 1px solid #eee;
}

.StripeElement--invalid {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for posting the update, that was the only thing that worked for me.

Answer (score 18):

Great question! As noted here, to apply padding or a border to a Stripe element you want to style the parent DOM node that contains the element, not the element itself:

https://stripe.com/docs/elements/reference#the-element-container

I'd wrap your CardElement in a div and then apply styling to that. As noted above, Elements automatically applies the `StripeElement` class to the parent element, as well as complete/empty/focus/invalid states.

Comment: The link above is now a 404. The updated page is here: https://stripe.com/docs/js/element/the_element_container

Answer (score 15):

The simplest solution is:

```
<div
  style={
    {
     border: '2px solid red'
    }
  }
>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6):

I was trying to add padding, and the wrapper div did not work for me. However, they [added a change](https://github.com/stripe/react-stripe-elements/issues/51) to react-stripe-elements to allow for a `className` on the card element. That worked for me:

In my css:

```
.card-element {
  padding: 11.4px 12px;
}
```

For my CardElement:

```
<CardElement style={style} className="card-element" />
```

You still have to use inline styling for the attributes that are in the element options styles: https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/reference#element-options

Answer (score 3):

In the docs there is a reference to an [`options`](https://stripe.com/docs/js/elements_object/create_element?type=card#elements_create-options) prop which you can add to the `CardElement` component:

```
const cardElementOptions = {
  style: {
    base: {
      color: "#666",
      fontSize: "20px",
    },
    invalid: {
      color: "#fa755a",
      fontSize: "20px",
    }
  }
}

return (
  <form onSubmit={handleOnSubmit}>
    <CardElement options={cardElementOptions} />
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
)
```

See also https://stripe.com/docs/js/appendix/style

Comment: Unfortunately border, and maybe other CSS properties, are not available via the options prop.

Answer (score 0):

There is an appearance api (https://stripe.com/docs/elements/appearance-api ) where you can see what CSS properties you can use on style object in options prop.

For now I have found a couple of ways of styling.

1. Trough options prop with style object.
2. Adding a classname to the element.
3. If you tend to use flex you need to wrap your elements in two divs like this:

```html
   <div style={{ display: "flex" }}>
          <div style={{ flexBasis: "100%" }}>
            <CardExpiryElement
              options={options}
              className="cardExpiryElement"
            />
          </div>
          <div style={{ flexBasis: "100%" }}>
            <CardCvcElement options={options} className="cardCvcElement" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```